# Is there default helper method complementing "+" operator in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to show "+" operator if the value is above zero like:

```
num = 0.44
operator = num > 0 ? "+" : ""
operator + helper.number_to_percentage(num)
=> "+0.440%"
```

Is there default helper method that make it possible same function like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
num = 0.44    
'%+.3f%' % num #=> "+0.440%"
```

Comment: ironsand, if the precision is a variable, you can write (with double quotes): `num = 0.44; p=4; "%+.#{p}f%" % num #=> "+0.4400%`; if you also want the field 10 characters wide: `"%+10.#{p}f%" % num
 #=> "   +0.4400%"`. See [String#%](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-25) and [Kernel#sprintf](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) for details.